# Apache Cassandra gridView issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, cassandra

I Can´t get rowkey value displayed on gridview from Apache-Cassandra.
some of the code...

```
public class PacienteEntity
{
    public int key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

var records = (from x in context.ColumnList
where x.ColumnFamily == "paciente"
select x.ToObject<PacienteEntity>());

//remove null rows
var filteredRecords = records.ToList().Where(i => i != null);
dgView.DataSource = filteredRecords.ToList();
dgView.DataBind();
```

rowkey value is equal 0 even using autoGenerateColumns
Any help will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I basically pass the `RowIndex` via `CommandArgument` and use it to retrieve the `DataKey` value like
On the Button:

> CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'

On the Server Event

> int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
>
> string val = (string)this.dgView.DataKeys[rowIndex]["myKey"];

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Data Key Names in Gridview like below

```
  <asp:gridview id="MyGridView" 
        datakeynames="Key"
        onselectedindexchanged="MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
        runat="server">
```

Then in your event you can get the key as below

```
  void MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    int index = MyGridView.SelectedIndex;
    var key =MyGridView.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
  }
```

if you have already multiple keys like `DataKeyNames="Key,Name"`

You can now access each of DataKeys by providing its index like below:

```
string Key= MyGridView.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();
string Name= MyGridView.DataKeys[index].Values[1].ToString();
```

Not sure about your DataSource binding, Please do as below, You need to map correct properties to set Key and Name in below code

```
var records = context.ColumnList.Where(x=> x.ColumnFamily == "paciente")
              .Select(p=> new PacienteEntity(){ Key = p.P_Key, Name =p.P_Name}).ToList();
```

Comment: Damith, I fact I´m unable to have displayed the rowkey value corresponding to 'name id'

Comment: key | name
--------------------------------
0   | carlos henckes

Comment: Damith, may be I can make myself clear. I'm just trying to bind data to gridview, but rowkey value is not displayed. I dont't need to access the value. Pagination works fine.

Comment: @CarlosHenckes You have to map with correct proper, I don't have idea about your classes :), which fields you need to map as key and value?

Comment: ...like this: public class PacienteEntity
{
public int key { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}
sorry damith, i´m new to this... school project.